# Java: search for an object by name in .class files

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-bytecode

I need to find the path to the object class in the files .class without initialization.

For example, I have a string "java.lang.System.out", I need to get "java.io.PrintStream", since "out" is "PrintStream". I have no idea how this can be done.

At the moment I am writing a compiler for the JVM, and there I need to specify the class of the object that is being accessed. Public objects are not deleted by the compiler.

Comment: Are you familiar with [the class file format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se19/html/jvms-4.html)? You must be, if you are writing a compiler for the JVM. So parse the class file to find the required field and its type there.

Comment: @apangin , Yes, I am familiar with the class file format. I assumed that this could already be implemented in Java.

Comment: There are many existing class file parsers in Java, just take any that is most convenient to you. Note that questions seeking for recommendations for libraries are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Of course, this has been implemented in Java already, more than once. But you deliberately decided to write your own compiler, so your goals define the constraints on reusing existing software, but we don’t know them if you don’t post them.